# CentOS 6 how to clear machine ID for a template?

Tags: centos, template

I want to create a template from CentOS 6 so that each VM feels like a unique install. I found `sys-unconfig` which works but I don't like that it asks for a new password on boot. What alternatives are there?

Comment: That doesn't work on centos6

Comment: “Doesn’t work” ... in what way?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your image format and how you create the image in the first place however I generally use virt-sysprep to unconfigure images, details can be found here: "http://libguestfs.org/virt-sysprep.1.html"
The command would look something like this:

```
# virt-sysprep --operations ssh-hostkeys,udev-persistent-net,machine-id -a disk.img
```

I would then look at using cloud-init to configure the new VMs on bootup, again this depends on your hypervisor technology on how this would need to be configured.
http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/